# Bootstrap overwrites my custom stylesheet after a jQuery event occurs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, overwrite

I am using my own .css stylesheet to overwrite some Bootstrap CSS rules, in this particular case I want the `navbar-brand` image display as 'inline-block', not as 'block', like specifies bootstrap.css.

No problem with that, I have my navbar-brand image handled by my 'custom.css', with 'display: inline-block', until an event that changes the 'src' attribute is fired:

```
var logoChanged = false;

$(window).on("resize",function(){

var screen = $(window).width();

if(screen<390 && !logoChanged){
    $("navbar-brand img").attr("src","img/logo-aure2.png");
    logoChanged=true;
    });
}else if(screen>390 && logoChanged){
    $("navbar-brand img").attr("src","img/logo-aurestudio.png");
    logoChanged=false;
    });
}

});
```

The function works fine and the 'src' attribute changes correctly when resizing the screen, but after that, navbar-brand returns to be handled by bootstrap.css and not by my custom.css, displaying the image as a 'block' again.

Anyone know why this happens?

Thanks a lot

Comment: please add navbar-brand css codes in custom.css to your question...

Comment: a lot of bootstrap css cannot be overridden and it eventually takes effect and if you inspect the element in chrome a lot of times u will find bootstrap overriding the styles so if you want to make permanent changes add them in bootstrap.css file which you will download if you're self hosting bootstrap..